# using only static members within a class

Tags: c++

Is it sensible to have a class with static data members only? The class I'm trying to implement looks like:

```
class myClass{
private:
//list of static data members
public:
//set of methods
}
```

The methods make use of the static data and modify them during run-time. I've never had to write a class that uses only static data, but looks a bit odd to me with 7 of those members. So I was wondering if this is well-viewed from the C++ program standards.

Comment: Consider using a `namespace` instead

Comment: Well-viewed screams opinion. Sounds like an XY problem. If all of your variables are `static`, you probably didn't design your class well.

Comment: another possibility might be a normal class which you make one static instance of

Comment: Are you looking for a singleton?

Comment: You're basically implementing a singleton. Some view this as an anti-pattern, while others see it as a good practice in certain scenarios. An alternative is to use a namespace and declare the variables as static members of another namespace declared in your .cpp file (making them *more* inaccessible than private members of a class).

Comment: my program will only create one instance of the class, does that mean creating the class as singleton should be the best solution as opposed to creating a namespace? This is for an assignment, and if there is some controversy on the advantages/drawbacks of using singleton vs namespace, then I'd rather go for the safest

Comment: @Sr: there is absolutely no need to create an instance in this case; all static members will be available without any instance created, using `myClass::member`. Moreover, you should even follow tobi's advice and make constructor private in order to prevent from creating an instance.

Comment: Singletons are bad, ugh.

Comment: if all members are static, you dont even need a single instance. Afaik Singletons are not inherently bad, it is just a bit complicated to get it right in c++ and most of the time there are better and easier ways to achieve the same

Comment: @tobi303 Singletons are bad. They are glorified global variables. Adding state to your program is _bad news_.

Comment: @erip you might be completely right, but anyhow thats a different topic. If I had to choose between a singleton and the OPs approach I would choose the OPs for sure (which is global variables with a breeze of java flavour, but still better than a singleton imho). Global variables are not nice in general, no matter in what form, but there is too little information to suggest something "better" here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imho there is nothing wrong with this approach. It just looks a bit java-ish. The static members act basically as global variables packed inside a class. Putting them inside the class has the advantage of having a natural way of defining setters and getters (which seems to be a requirement in your case).

The downside is that for a user it might be not obvious that it does not really make sense to create objects of that class. However, this you can simply prevent by making the constructor private.